# dynamically hide ExtJS 4 grid column when grouping on column

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an ExtJS 4 gridPanel as below:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    title: 'grid',
    columns: [
        {text: 'column 1', sortable: true, width: 70, dataIndex: 'column1'},
        {text: 'column 2', sortable: true, width: 70, dataIndex: 'column2'},
        {text: 'column 3', sortable: true, width: 70, dataIndex: 'column3'},
        {text: 'column 4', sortable: true, width: 70, dataIndex: 'column4'},
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.get('gridDiv'),
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    listeners: {
    },
    features: [{
        ftype: 'grouping'
    }]
});
```

I'm required to dynamically hide the column that the grid is being grouped by whenever the grid is grouped, and show all other columns - reshowing any previously hidden columns.

I understand that this would be a listener handler that catches the grouping changing, which would then fire `column.hide()`.

Some pseudo-code:

```
...
listeners: {
    groupchange: function(store, groupers, eOpts) {
        groupers.forEach(function(group) {
            grid.columns.forEach(function(column) {
                if(column==group)
                    column.hide();
                if(column==group)
                    column.show();
            }
        }
    }
},
...
```

I'm not sure from the API documentation whether `groupchange` is an event that can be caught by the grid, rather than the store, how to access the contents of `groupers`, and what comparators are available to determine if a column is in `groupers`.

How should this listener event be structured? What are the correct events/methods/properties to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the hiding is done on a store listener, despite the grid panel API making it look as though it can be done as a grid listener. I've worked off the first `keys` array value within the groupers, although you could just as easily use `items[0].property` value.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    ...
    listeners:
    {
        groupchange: function(store, groupers, eOpts){
            var column = groupers.keys[0];
            productionItemGrid.columns.forEach(function(entry){
                if(entry.dataIndex == column)
                {
                    entry.setVisible(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    entry.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: I don't have time to check your answer but I like that your "giving back" by answering your own question